# Removing .php from example.com/.php

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

For removing just .php from my urls, I currently have the following

```
# Remove trailing slashes
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1 [NC,L,R=301] 

# Remove trailing .php extensions
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\S*?)/(.*?)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [L,R=301]

# Add .php extension for final internal redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule !\.php$ %1.php [NC,L]
```

But these rules do not work for bare `example.com` as it ends up as `example.com/.php`. So how can I fix that?

Comment: _Aside:_ Presumably you removed the `.php` extension in the application itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either:

- Check that the destination file (with the `.php` extension) exists *before* internally rewriting to it
- Avoid rewriting directories (for which the document root is one).
- Avoid rewriting the document root only (as in your example).

For example, to avoid rewriting the document root only, as in your specific example, you can modify the existing `RewriteCond` directive:

> ```
> # Add .php extension for final internal redirect
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
> ```

to read:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.+)$
```

`/.+` matches a slash followed by *something*, which would exclude the document root, since the document root is naturally a slash by itself.

---

To avoid rewriting all directories (of which the document root is one), you can add an additional condition to avoid rewriting URLs that map to a physical directory. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.php$ %1.php [NC,L]
```

However, if you have directories that are accessible then you should modify your existing rule that removes trailing slashes, otherwise, you will likely get a redirect loop when requesting a directory (since mod_dir will append a slash by default). For example:

> ```
> # Remove trailing slashes
> RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1 [NC,L,R=301]
> ```

Should be modified to include the same condition as above:

```
# Remove trailing slashes, unless the request maps to a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Also, no need for the `NC` flag here. And there is no need to escape the slash in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

I assume you must also have a `RewriteBase` directive defined elsewhere in you file, otherwise, this will likely result in an invalid redirect in `.htaccess`.

Comment: It works as expected, but before I accept the answers I'd like to ask a few more questions if you don't mind. 1. Why the file check if the server generates a not found automatically?  2. For avoiding directories, I presume I should add a flag to the trailing slash remover?

Comment: 1. Yes, that is possibly unnecessary, although it does avoid a meaningless rewrite and corresponding access log entry. But, importantly, it would solve your current problem of rewriting to `/.php`, which is why I've included that here. 2. I've updated my answer.